# How to return the amount of difference from a recursive dictionary check

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I am checking the differences in keys,values from two dictionaries. However I am able to print the differences, but I would like to save the outcome in a variable (are there differences or not, or how many differences are there).

```
def findDiff(d1, d2, path="", differences = 0):
    for k in d1:
        if (k not in d2):
            print (path, ":")
            print (k + " as key not in d2", "\n")
            differences += 1
        else:
            if type(d1[k]) is dict:
                if path == "":
                    path = k
                else:
                    path = path + "->" + k
                findDiff(d1[k], d2[k], path, differences)
            else:
                if d1[k] != d2[k]:
                    print (path, ":")
                    print (" - ", k," : ", d1[k])
                    print (" + ", k," : ", d2[k])
                    differences += 1
    return differences

a = findDiff(moot_params, database_params)

print(a)
```

This however always results in None if the last dictionary doesn't contain any differences.

Does anybody know how I can return a value using this recursion?

Comment: Does changing `findDiff(d1[k], d2[k], path, differences)` to `differences += findDiff(d1[k], d2[k], path)` work?

Comment: Yes it does! Sometimes the solution isn't that complicated. Thanks for the fresh look

Comment: Alright great, I'll write an answer explaining why that fix worked.

Comment: I would encourage you to clarify the purpose of `findDiff()` in your own mind: is its purpose to return information about the differences between two dicts (ie, return data); or is it to print information about the differences between two dicts (ie, print stuff)? When writing functions, pick one or the other, not both. And, really, the only sensible choice is the first one (return data), because if you do a good job with that part, it's almost always easy to write a different function to take that information and print it out in various ways.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion FMc, for the program it is only required to get the amount of changes. (differences), however if there is a difference, it is usefull to print the actual difference to avoid manually searching it. But I agree, the sole purpose should be a flag: equal or not (I could off returned a boolean instead)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have to change `findDiff(d1[k], d2[k], path, differences)` to `differences += findDiff(d1[k], d2[k], path)` (as I indicated in the comment) is because Python arguments are [passed by assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference), and integers are immutable. To make a change in an integer, instead of passing it into the function and changing it inside, you should return how much you're changing it from within inside (as seen in the link's example).

If you don't quite understand the link and integer immutability yet, in simple terms, it means that when you modify `differences` in `findDiff(d1[k], d2[k], path, differences)`, the `differences` you already have on the "outside" will not get modified. The solution is to explicitly change `differences` using `+=`, giving the recursive functionality you desire.